# How to trigger Informatica mapping task based on output of Snowflake query?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, informatica, iics, iics-di

My current company is ingesting data from S3 to Snowflake using Informatica. After the data ingestion job is completed, we are adding a new entry to table called "INFORMATICA_JOBS" that contains the schema and table name, the number of rows processed and the timestamp.

INFORMATICA_JOBS table in snowflake:

| table | rows | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| schema_A.table1 | 123 | 2023-06-06 13:02 |

I need to monitor this table and if the "rows" column is 0 for any of the tables then I need to login to Informatica and manually run the mapping task and see if the table has been populated. I have been trying to automate this and what I came up with is that - I can create a TASK in snowflake that returns the count of rows where the "rows" column is 0 i.e.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK CheckTableForZeroRowsTask
  WAREHOUSE = warehouse_name
  SCHEDULE = 'DAILY'
AS
USE ROLE dev_role;
USE WAREHOUSE warehouse_name;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM schema_A.table_name WHERE rows=0;
```

But I am not sure how to trigger the Informatica mapping task to run if the above Snowflake task says that the "rows" column does have 0.

Comment: Why not just do this in Informatica with a scheduled workflow?

Answer (score 0):

This task you've created runs `DAILY`.

It's not possible to make API calls from within Snowflake Task - as per [the Snowflake docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tasks-intro) they are used to manipulate data:

> A task can execute any one of the following types of SQL code:
>
> - Single SQL statement
> - Call to a stored procedure
> - Procedural logic using Snowflake Scripting

You should consider creating Informatica Taskflow, schedule it to run daily, run the query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM schema_A.table_name WHERE rows=0;` and for each resulting row call appropriate taskflow API to run them.

Comment: We are already using automatic alert both for success and failures during ingestion in our Informatica jobs. But there was an exception that happened in the previous Informatica data ingestion run where, out of 70 tables only in 1 table data was not loaded, but it produced a success email alert instead of error. So I am a bit skeptical relying on Informatica taskflow for this.

Comment: So this seems you have a bug in your code - fix it instead of producing another feature on top of it :). As mentioned, Tasks in Snowflake will not execute anything outside Snowflake - they allow data manipulation within Snowflake only.